# LINQ Get full list of objects, include only the properties that match certain condition

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these two models:

```cs
    public class Seat
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    //..
    }

    public class Reservation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SeatId { get; set; }
        public Seat Seat { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        //..
    }
```

Say a seat has a reservations for every day of the week. I want to make a query that takes the seats and filters the reservations for the seats for a requested day. I want to display the seats and show which ones are free/reserved for the day X. 
The ways I tried to achieve it:

```cs
        var seats = _dbContext.Seats
             .Include(s => s.Reservations.Where(r => r.DateTime.Date == dateParam.Date));
        // InvalidOperationException: 'Lambda expression used 
        // inside Include is not valid.'
```

Sample

```cs
       var seats = _dbContext.Seats
             .Include(s => s.Reservations)
             .Where(r => r.Reservations.Any(r => r.DateTime.Date == dateParam.Date));   
        // Gets the seats which meet the condition. I want these, but also I want the free seats
```

Sample

```cs
        var seatsFiltered = _dbContext.Seats
             .Include(t => t.Reservations)
             .Where(r => r.Reservations.Any(r => r.DateTime.Date == dateParam.Date))
             .ToList();

        var seats = _dbContext.Seats
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => { x.Reservations = new List<Reservation>(); return x; })
             .Concat(seatsFiltered);
        // Not optimal since I obviously ToList twice
        // In the end I get an empty list

        return (ICollection<Seat>)seats;
```

EDIT: Add sample data as requested:

Seats

```
Id|AreaId|
--|------|
 1|3     | 
 2|3     |
 3|3     |
 4|3     |
 5|3     |
 6|3     |
 7|3     |
 8|3     |
```

Reservations

```
Id|SeatId|Name|Phone|DateTime           |
--|------|----|-----|-------------------|
 7|     1|    |     |2020-02-15 20:30:00|
 8|     1|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
 9|     1|    |     |2020-02-23 09:00:00|
10|     2|    |     |2020-02-15 20:30:00|
11|     2|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
12|     2|    |     |2020-02-23 09:00:00|
13|     4|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
15|     7|    |     |2020-02-15 20:30:00|
16|     7|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
17|     8|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
14|     8|    |     |2020-02-23 09:00:00|
18|     3|    |     |2020-02-15 20:30:00|
19|     3|    |     |2020-02-21 12:00:00|
20|     3|    |     |2020-02-23 09:00:00|
```

When I tried the code by Phong, I got the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
>   KeySelector: (r.SeatId), 
>   ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: Reservation
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False
>   )
>   )
>       .ToList()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Comment: Could you please give us your sample data with corresponding the result?

Comment: Besides, `Reservation` should not contain `Seat` object. It's already contained `SeatId` to be able to reference.

Comment: Ok `Seat` could be redundant, I've just followed a guide about making the relation. The result for 2020-02-15 would return all the seats including the reservations that have a `DateTime` value of `2020-02-15 20:30:00` since that's the one I've used as sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phong's solution might be absolutely valid and useful but since I couldn't understand it myself and apply it, I used this method

```cs
var seats = _dbContext.Seats.ToList();
var reservations = _dbContext.Reservations.Where(r => r.DateTime.Day == dateTime.Day).ToList();

foreach (var seat in seats)
{
    seat.Reservations = reservations.Where(r => r.SeatId == seat.Id).ToList();
}
```

I still believe there's also a LINQ one-liner that can do this, without the performance hit of `.ToList()`-ing every collection but I couldn't figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) like below.

```
var seatsFiltered = _dbContext.Reservations
                          .Where(r => r.DateTime.Date == dateParam.Date))
                          .GroupBy(r => r.SeatId)
                          .Select(g => new 
{
  SeatId = g.Key,
  ListOfReservations = g // No need to .ToList() here
}) .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I try out your code I get an unhandled exception. I guess I'll need some time to understand both the code and the exception. Meanwhile I'll paste the exception message into my question (too long for a comment).

Comment: What kind of Entity Framework you are using ? EF 6 or EF core ?

Comment: Anyway, remove `.TolList` in `ListOfReservations = g.ToList()` to `ListOfReservations = g` please

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Dragomir